# Нужна помощь в сортировки объекта по ключу типа float

Tags: javascript

Нужна помощь в сортировки объекта по ключу типа float, ответы которые нашел не дали никакого результата.

Две разные сортировки, по возрастанию и по убыванию.

```js
var obj = {
  112.532: "7235",
  752.139: "2325",
  612.512: "2235",
  2312.12: "2235"
}

console.log(obj);
console.log(obj);
```

Как добиться такой сортировки?

По возрастанию:

```
"112.532": "7235",
"612.512": "2235",
"752.139": "2325",
"2312.12": "872",
...
```

По убыванию:

```
"2312.12": "872",
"752.139": "2325",
"612.512": "2235",
"112.532": "7235",
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function sortFloatKeys(obj, desc) {
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  keys.sort((a, b) => {
    var d = +a - +b;
    return desc? -d : d;
  });
  var res = {};
  keys.forEach(i => res[i] = obj[i]);
  return res;
}

var obj = {
  112.532: "7235",
  752.139: "2325",
  612.512: "2235",
  2312.12: "2235"
};

console.log(sortFloatKeys(obj, false));
console.log(sortFloatKeys(obj, true));
```